# Hiding Webview while streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

For a online radio streaming app, I have the code below so far. The problem that I have is when I press play, a webview opens up and when I close it the stream stops. How do I make this webview not appear on the screen/do it in the background?

`ViewController.h`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

-(IBAction)play:(id)sender;
```

`ViewController.m`

```
-(IBAction)play:(id)sender
{
    NSString *stream = @"STREAMING LINK";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stream];
    NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlrequest];
}
```

Also while using webview, would I be able to make a pause/stop button and a volume switch as well?

Answer (score 0):

Forget Interface Builder, and do it programmatically.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"STREAMING LINK"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

Comment: Where should this code go? In the Play IBAction or in ViewController interface?

Comment: In your -(IBAction)play:(id)sender

Comment: I tried to add this but it's not playing when I press the button. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you wait until it starts? 6-7 seconds for example.. I did the same and it s working

Comment: Yes I did but still no sound.